# How to use Advanced Custom Fields and Fancybox correctly

Tags: wordpress, fancybox, advanced-custom-fields

I have a Wordpress template with an ACF repeater field showing coaches in a ski club. There are sub-fields for member `name, title, email, picture and bio`.

Everything works fine except the `bio field`, I am trying to open the bio with `fancybox` using the `easy-fancybox plugin` but **it will only open the first bio submitted when either bio link is clicked on**. *I need it to open the bio that is submitted in that coaches specific sub-field*. I am assuming that I have an issue somewhere with my `php code` relating to `fancybox` or the `‘hidden’ div`. If I do not use `fancybox` & simply echo `$bio` it shows the correct `bio` but it then shows the whole `bio` on the page.

[Here is the page:](http://tssc.org/team-gravity-coaches/)

Here is the template code:

```
<section class="content">
<?php get_template_part('inc/page-title'); ?>

<div class="pad group">
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<div class="member_info">
  <?php if( have_rows('member_info') ): ?>
  <?php while( have_rows('member_info') ): the_row(); 
                      // vars
                      $name = get_sub_field('member_name');
                      $title = get_sub_field('member_title');
                      $email = get_sub_field('member_email');
                      $image = get_sub_field('member_picture');
                      $bio = get_sub_field('member_bio');
                  ?>

  <div class="member_content">
    <div class="member_pic">
  <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt'] ?>" />
</div>

    <ul>
      <li><?php echo $name; ?></li>

      <li><?php echo $title; ?></li>

      <li><?php if( $email ): ?></li>

        <a href="mailto:<?php the_sub_field('member_email'); ?>"><?php echo $email; ?></a>
        <?php endif; ?>

      <li><?php if( $bio ): ?></li>
        <a class="fancybox-inline" href="#bio">BIO</a> <?php endif; ?>
    </ul>

    <div style="display: none;">
      <div id="bio">
        <p><?php echo the_sub_field('member_bio'); ?></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 <?php endwhile; ?>
 <?php endif; ?><
 ?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
</div><!--/.pad-->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try assign the different ids number on anchor href="#bio1" and same id assign to div. following is example code i am pasting.

```html
  

<section class="content">
<?php get_template_part('inc/page-title'); ?>

<div class="pad group">
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<div class="member_info">
  <?php if( have_rows('member_info') ): ?>
  <?php $i=1; while( have_rows('member_info') ): the_row(); 
                      // vars
                      $name = get_sub_field('member_name');
                      $title = get_sub_field('member_title');
                      $email = get_sub_field('member_email');
                      $image = get_sub_field('member_picture');
                      $bio = get_sub_field('member_bio');
                  ?>

  <div class="member_content">
    <div class="member_pic">
  <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt'] ?>" />
</div>

    <ul>
      <li><?php echo $name; ?></li>

      <li><?php echo $title; ?></li>

      <li><?php if( $email ): ?></li>

        <a href="mailto:<?php the_sub_field('member_email'); ?>"><?php echo $email; ?></a>
        <?php endif; ?>

      <li><?php if( $bio ): ?></li>
        <a class="fancybox-inline" href="#bio<?php echo $i;?>">BIO</a> <?php endif; ?>
    </ul>

    <div style="display: none;">
      <div id="bio<?php echo $i;?>">
        <p><?php echo the_sub_field('member_bio'); ?></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 <?php $i++; endwhile; ?>
 <?php endif; ?><
 ?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
</div><!--/.pad-->
```